# How to make reiterations using yes/no prompt?

Tags: c, loops, iteration

I realize a there is an issue with my data overflowing, but my main concern is trying to re run the program at the end to start all over. I've looked through multiple examples through this website, but couldn't really find one that fit my need.

I am not sure if you can see the first part of my code, but I essentially tried to use someones do while example for my program but i just can't figure it out.

If anyone could give any suggestions I would greatly appreciate it!

I'm sure if i keep at it i'll figure it out eventually, but i thought this would be a good question for this website.

Here is my source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
 int days;/* user will input number of days light will travel*/
 int answer;
 char buffer[256];

 printf(" \n" );
 printf("\t**-**-**-**Welcome to the LIGHT RAY!**-**-**-**\n");
 printf(" \n" );
 printf("\tTo get an idea of how unbelieveably fast light is!\n");
 printf("\t come climb aboard the LIGHT RAY!\n", );
 do
 {
   printf(" \n" );
   printf(" \n");
   printf("\tHow many days would you like to travel?\n");
   scanf("%d", &days);

   printf("processing...\n" ) /* fictional terminal computing information*/;
   sleep(2);
   printf("Initializing warp drive...\n" );
   sleep(1);

   printf("3\n" ) /* count down sequence*/;
   sleep(1);
   printf("2\n" );
   sleep(1);
   printf("1\n" );
   sleep(1);
   printf("SHROOOOM!\n" );
   sleep(1);

   int day_time=days * 86400/*86,400 seconds is equal to 1 day*/;
   int distance=day_time*186000/*light travels 186,000 miles per second!*/;



   printf("Congratulations, you have traveled %lld miles! \n",distance);
   printf("Would you like another go?(yes, no)\n" );
   scanf("%s\n", buffer );
 }while (strcmp(buffer, "yes") !=0);

 getchar();

 return 0;
```

}

Comment: You should compile with full warnings (`-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic` on gcc), and fix all of the warnings. Aside: To get good warnings on gcc, you need to set it to optimize as well (`-O3`).

Comment: Don't use `int` use `double` because `86400 * 186000` is already out of the range of a 32-bit signed int for 1 day, let alone a year.

Comment: `while (strcmp(buffer, "yes") !=0)` should be testing `==0` to match the strings.

Comment: @WeatherVane Why use a `double` and not a `long long` or  (even better) an `uint64_t`? No need to bring messy floating point in if necessary :)

Comment: Dont' use `scanf ("%s\n", buffer)` here - use `fgets (buffer, 255, stdin)` instead to be safe (and avoid a buffer overflow).  Note that `fgets` automatically appends a NULL character to the input, so we use 255 instead of 256 to leave room for it.

Comment: @tonysdg it needs 1 mile accuracy? The `double` type can hold a value to `10^308` whereas `uint64_t` can only store a feeble `10^19`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Look, friend, I can only count to `10^1` - after that I run out of fingers ;)

Comment: @tonysdg I met the trajectory engineer for the spacecraft *Cassini* (she's not on board) and she has only 10 fingers too. I bet she doesn't use integer arithmetic to calculate orbits.

Comment: @WeatherVane Haha I concede the point (1) because you've got irrefutable logic and (2) because you've got amazing contacts.  Kudos!

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be enough to give you an idea:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int     validate;
    char    menu_choice;


        validate = 0;
        do{
            printf("Would you like another go?(y/n):\t" );

            if(scanf(" %c", &menu_choice ) == 1){
                if((menu_choice=='y') || (menu_choice=='Y')){
                    printf("You choosed Yes\n\n\n");
                    validate = 1;
                }else if((menu_choice=='n') || (menu_choice=='N')){
                    printf("You choosed No\n\n\n");
                    validate = 2;
                }else{
                    printf("Wrong Input.\n\n\n");
                    validate = 0;
                }
            }
        }while( validate == 0 || validate == 1);

        printf("Goodbye\n");

    return 0;
}
```

> ```
> Would you like another go?(y/n):  1
> Wrong Input.
> ```

```
Would you like another go?(y/n):    k
Wrong Input.


Would you like another go?(y/n):    y
You choosed Yes


Would you like another go?(y/n):    Y
You choosed Yes


Would you like another go?(y/n):    N
You choosed No


Goodbye
```

For things like this i prefer instead something like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int checkInput(int min, int max){
    int option,check;
    char c;

    do{
        printf("Please type a number beetwen %d and %d:\t",min,max);

        if(scanf("%d%c",&option,&c) == 0 || c != '\n'){
            while((check = getchar()) != 0 && check != '\n');
            printf("\tI sayed a Number please\n\n");
        }else if(option < min || option > max){
            printf("\tThe number has to be beetwen %d and %d\n\n",min,max);
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }while(1);

    return option;
}

int main(void){
    int number = checkInput(0,1);

    printf("\nYour number is\t%d\n",number);

    return 0;
}
```

> ```
> Please type a number beetwen 0 and 1: 2e
>     I sayed a Number please
> ```

```
Please type a number beetwen 0 and 1:   g45
    I sayed a Number please

Please type a number beetwen 0 and 1:   75
    The number has to be beetwen 0 and 1

Please type a number beetwen 0 and 1:   1

Your number is  1
```

But if you insist to use yes/no instead of Y/N, then;

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<strings.h>

int main(void){
    int     validate;
    char    menu_choice[5];
    char *yes = "yes";
    char *no = "no";

        validate = 0;
        do{
            printf("Would you like another go?(yes/no):\t" );

            if(scanf(" %s", menu_choice ) == 1){
                if((strcasecmp(menu_choice, yes) == 0)){
                    printf("You choosed Yes\n\n\n");
                    validate = 1;
                }else if((strcasecmp(menu_choice, no) == 0)){
                    printf("You choosed No\n\n\n");
                    validate = 2;
                }else{
                    printf("Wrong Input.\n\n\n");
                    validate = 0;
                }
            }
        }while( validate == 0 || validate == 1);

        printf("Goodbye\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> ```
> Would you like another go?(yes/no):   sadasdas
> Wrong Input.
> ```

```
Would you like another go?(yes/no): 213212
Wrong Input.


Would you like another go?(yes/no): Yes
You choosed Yes


Would you like another go?(yes/no): YeS
You choosed Yes


Would you like another go?(yes/no): YES
You choosed Yes


Would you like another go?(yes/no): No
You choosed No


Goodbye
```

Please make notice that **strcasecmp** is found in **strings.h** and not in **string.h**.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your input your feedback is truly invaluable! I will likely  refer back to this one day if i may need it

If any of you are interested here's my final product, even though I may continue to fiddle with it:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
  int days;/* user will input number of days light will travel*/
  int validate=0;
  char menu_choice;/* choices... choices*/

  printf(" \n" );
  printf("\t**-**-**-**Welcome to the LIGHT RAY!**-**-**-**\n");/*carny introduction */
  printf(" \n" );
  printf("\tCome one come all \n" );
  printf("\tget an idea of how unbelieveably fast light is!\n");
  do{/*loop for return trip*/
      printf("\tTake a trip on the LIGHT RAY?(y/n):\t" );
      if(scanf(" %c", &menu_choice ) == 1){
          if((menu_choice=='y') || (menu_choice=='Y')){

              printf("\tAhh... Good choice!\n\n");/*responce and input*/
              printf(" \n" );
              printf(" \n");
              printf("\tHow many days would you like to travel?\t");
              scanf("%d", &days);

              printf("processing...\n" ) /* fictional terminal computing information*/;
              sleep(2);
              printf("Initializing warp drive...\n" );
              sleep(1);

              printf("3\n" ) /* count down sequence*/;
              sleep(1);
              printf("2\n" );
              sleep(1);
              printf("1\n" );
              sleep(1);
              printf("SHROOOOM!\n\n" );
              sleep(1);

              long long day_time=days * 86400/*86,400 seconds is equal to 1 day*/;
              long long distance=day_time*186000/*light travels 186,000 miles per second!*/;


              printf("Congratulations, you managed not to get trapped in the space time continuum and manage to travel %lld miles! \n\n",distance);



              validate = 1;
          }else if((menu_choice=='n') || (menu_choice=='N')){
              printf("\n" );
              printf("\tStep aside you're holding up the line!!!\n\n\n");
              validate = 2;
          }else{
              printf("\n" );
              printf("\tWHAT did you just call my mother!.\n\n\n");
              validate = 0;
          }
      }
  }while( validate == 0 || validate == 1);





  getchar();

  return 0;
}
```

One last thought, would it be possible to change the action statement after the first iteration
for example:

Do you wish to embark on a trip through the LIGHT RAY?

.
.
.

Congratulations...

Do you wish to take another trip?
/*repeat loop*/

I also got some strange interactions when a character like "yes" is imputed for days_travel.

How would i cover for that, I'm thinking of a if then statement, but im not too sure how to structure it?